# Partial view not rendering through ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a controller action which is getting called by JQuery ajax, and hopefully returniung the contents of "Results" to the requesting page. 
So far I have...

Controller

```
    public ActionResult DynCalc(resultsModel model){
    ...
    //code that populates model - all working ok
    ...
     if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
          {
            return PartialView("results", model.Results);
          }
          else
          {
            return null; //Handle this later
          }
    }
```

This passes back a valid model.
Called from the javascript:

```
     $.ajax({
            url: "/Test/DynCalc",
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#frmResults").serialize(), //This part works
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (result) {
                $('#resultsSection').html(result);
                $('#hide_panel a').flash("#111", 1000);
            }
        });
```

Sucess is never hit. Hopefully somebody can just tell me i'm being daft and missing something obvious?

My partial view results is just a HTML page with javascript on it. If I just have the following

`Hello world` in my results view, then  it works ok, with any script in, it doesn't

Am I on the right track? Should I be changing the type of return on the controller? Or using JSON?

I didn't post the contents of the results page, as It doesn't matter if it's a whole document or simply `<b>hi</b>` - it does the same thing.

Comment: By JQ I assume you mean jquery? I would recommend using Firefox with Firebug to debug this. You can step through it and see what is actually happening, and monitor the network traffic. Also add a failure/error event handler since if its not success its failure/error and that will also tell you something.

Comment: @DaleBurrell Yes, also I added a Fail handler and it was hit each time, with `results` being an object - which I can't inspect.

Comment: You couldn't inspect it in Firebug?

Comment: I don't use Firebug. I did check in a similar Chrome extension and I'm getting an error in my view I think. I'll take a look at the code in there first.

Comment: Doh, something had changed on the model that made a piece of Jquery invalid. It renders now, but is this still the best aproach? Are there any benefits in returning JSOn instead? Thanks for the idea about the inspector in the browser though, sometimes forget about it ;)

Comment: Whether to to return JSON or HTML is down to what you want to use it for. If you are displaying the result as HTML, then HTML is the correct format to return. If you want to return a javascript object containing data which you then do stuff with (fill a list, alert a message...) then JSON is the correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to return just a View. Because your result in this case is a complete View (because the action result could be HTML, XML, JSON...whatever). 
Use PartialView **only as a way to render part** of your View.

E.g. on your MasterPage you would like to "always" render user info: `@RenderAction("UserInfoAction", "UserController")`

Answer (score 0):

```
    var model= {
        "PropertyName1":$("#txt1").val(),
        "PropertyName1": $("#txt2").val(),         
       }

     $.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url: 'Url.Action("DynCalc","ControllerName")',
         data: JSON.stringify(model),
         contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
         success: function (data, status, xhr)
          {
         alert("The result is : " + status + ": " + data);
          },
         error: function (xhr)
         {
         alert(xhr.responseText);
         }
       });
```